# When do I update the APN pem

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pem

We are using the development APN pem currently.

We are about to submit app to the apple store for review for distribution

Shall we change the APN pem to distribution one now or only after apple's approval?

Currently for beta testing, we are using the build that uses development APN pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the Push Notification Cert on your server, instead you should provide one for each environment (development, production). You can create one certificate per environment for your app in the [Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate). This approach allows you to test your push notification code and setup from Debug-Builds as well as from AdHoc-, TestFlight- or AppStore-Builds.